# MPI_Allgather produces inconsistent results

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi, openmpi

I am having trouble with MPI_Allgather in part of a much large piece of software.

The following function gets passed a double and related flag that is different on each node, the function is then supposed to find the globally minimum double, and set all nodes to the corresponding values.

```
void set_dt_to_global_min (double *dt, int *flag) {
    int ierr, size;
    ierr = MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    if (size == 1)
        return;

    typedef struct DT_FLAG_ {
        double dt;
        int flag;
    } DT_FLAG;

    DT_FLAG local;
    DT_FLAG *gathered = (DT_FLAG *) malloc(size * sizeof(*gathered));

    local.dt = *dt;
    local.flag = *flag;

    MPI_Allgather(&local, sizeof(DT_FLAG), MPI_BYTE, gathered, sizeof(DT_FLAG), MPI_BYTE, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    int i, imin;
    for (imin = 0, i = 1; i < size; ++i) {
        if (gathered[imin].dt > gathered[i].dt) {
            imin = i;
        }
    }

    *dt = gathered[imin].dt;
    *flag = gathered[imin].flag;

    free(gathered);
}
```

I am running this on 6 nodes currently and I find the following error occurs **only** on Node 5 (which has the smallest value of dt):

- the true value of `gathered[0]` is replaced by `gathered[2]`
- the true value of `gathered[1]` is replaced by `gathered[3]`

I thought that perhaps this has something to do with MPI_COMM_WORLD as there is potentially a call to MPI_Comm_Split(); however, as yet, I do not understand that part of the code.

Anyone have any ideas?

-- EDIT: Updated the question to reflect that we actually need to hold on to a flag that is also associated to `dt` -- this means @suszterpatt suggestion is great for my initial question, but in fact wont work (I don't think) for this.

Comment: Why not use MPI_Allreduce instead?

Comment: @suszterpatt: Thanks, I wasn't aware of MPI_Allreduce (maintaining legacy code and learning MPI as I go). However, having looked at the function, I think the reason that it wasn't used originally, is that dt is actually part of a struct that gets passed in (rather than the simple case of just operating on a double as I have indicated here). I will see if I can make it work.

Comment: You can define custom operations to be used with Reduce. Perhaps that would help? http://www.netlib.org/utk/papers/mpi-book/node118.html#SECTION005120000000000000000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A recent update to `mpi-default-dev` seems to have fixed the problem -- I'll post more details when I can work out what change might have fixed it.